# redirect URL IIS on Windows 2008

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting

Hi I need to create for my **www.company.com** hosted in IIS with .NET apps...a specific RULE that when my URL contain **www.company.com/*.nsf/etc...*** redirect my request to a new external URL
**external.company.com/.nsf/etc...** (then reponde another web-server)

for example:

if the URL is **www.mywebsite/page/page.aspx&id=4**  responde IIS but when the URL is 
**www.mywebsite/page/page.nsf&id=4** IIS need to redirect the user to **external.mywebsite/page/page.nsf&id=4**

Is possible that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

The redirect rule needs to use 'Regular Expressions'.

The pattern you're looking for is:

```
^(.*)\.nsf(.*)$
```

and the Redirect URL would be:

```
http://external.mywebsite.com/{R:1}.nsf{R:2}
```

The action type would be 'Redirect' and redirect type can be `Permanent (301)`.